# How to add objects to DBus service from another process / program

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qdbus

I create a DBus service and add objects to it.

```
QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
connection.registerService(serviceName); // name, e.g. "foo"
QDBusConnection::sessionBus().registerObject(path, object, myoptions);
```

Fine, I can see my objects under "service" in the DBus monitor. Now I want to add more objects, but from another program (which is related, but independent).

There `connection.registerService(serviceName);` fails, as the service already exists. **How would I be able to register more objects under the same service name?**

Background: I have clients consuming the services. They do **not** know who provides the services, but just the service name. So they always refer to the same service name. But several providers shall provide the service.

I have tried to use no service name (empty string, just relying on the object path). But the proxies based on

```
QDBusAbstractInterface(serviceName, path, interfaceName.toUtf8().constData(), connection, parent)
```

do not seem to work with an empty ("") `serviceName` (correct?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't, one connection to dbus == one name. Connections are usually unix sockets or abstract sockets (on linux). You'll need to proxy calls from first connection using some kind or RPC ( or dbus call ) to other services and respond back results from first connection as well.